# Difference between type alias and NewType

Tags: python, typing

What is the difference between this:

```
INPUT_FORMAT_TYPE  = NewType('INPUT_FORMAT_TYPE', Tuple[str, str, str])
```

and this

```
INPUT_FORMAT_TYPE  = Tuple[str, str, str]
```

Functionally, both work but IDEs like PyCharm flag code like this:

```
return cast(INPUT_FORMAT_TYPE, ("*", "*", "All"))
```

Comment: The distinction is discussed in the documentation for [`NewType`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype). Is there a particular part that is unclear to you?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

`InputFormat` (renamed it to keep type notation consistent) can be a subtype or alias of `Tuple[str, str, str]`. Having it be a subtype (your first example) instead of an alias (your second example) is useful for a situation where you want to statically verify (through something like `mypy`) that all `InputFormat`s were made in a certain way. For example:

```
def new_input_format(a: str) -> InputFormat:
    return InputFormat((a, a * 2, a * 4))

def print_input_format(input_format: InputFormat):
    print(input_format)

print_input_format(new_input_format("a")) # Statement 1
print_input_format(("a", "aa", "aaa"))    # Statement 2
```

If `InputFormat` is declared as an alias (through `InputFormat = Tuple[str, str, str]`), both statements will statically verify. If `InputFormat` is declared as a subtype (through `InputFormat = NewType('InputFormat', Tuple[str, str, str])`), only the first statement will statically verify.

Now this isn't foolproof. A third statement such as:

```
print_input_format(InputFormat(("a", "aa", "aaa")))
```

will statically verify, yet it bypasses our careful `InputFormat` creator called `new_input_format`. However, by making `InputFormat` a subtype here we were forced to explicitly acknowledge that we're creating an input format through having to wrap the `tuple` in an `InputFormat`, which makes it easier to maintain this type of code and spot potential bugs in input format constructions.

Another example where `NewType` is beneficial over a type alias:

Let's say you had a database which we expose two functions for:

```
def read_user_id_from_session_id(session_id: str) -> Optional[str]:
    ...

def read_user(user_id: str) -> User:
    ...
```

intended to be called like this (exhibit A):

```
user_id = read_user_id_by_session_id(session_id)

if user_id:
    user = read_user(user_id)

    # Do something with `user`.
else:
    print("User not found!")
```

Forget about the fact that we can use a join here to make this only one query instead of two. Anyways, we want to only allow a return value of `read_user_id_from_session_id` to be used in `read_user` (since in our system, a user ID can only come from a session). We don't want to allow any value, reason being that it's probably a mistake. Imagine we did this (exhibit B):

```
user = read_user(session_id)
```

To a quick reader, it may appear correct. They'd probably think a `select * from users where session_id = $1` is happening. However, this is actually treating a `session_id` as a `user_id`, and with our current type hints it passes despite causing unintended behavior at runtime. Instead, we can change the type hints to this:

```
UserID = NewType("UserID", str)

def read_user_id_from_session_id(session_id: str) -> Optional[UserID]:
    ...

def read_user(user_id: UserID) -> User:
    ...
```

Exhibit A expressed above would still work, because the flow of data is correct. But we'd have to turn Exhibit B into

```
read_user(UserID(session_id))
```

which quickly points out the problem of converting a `session_id` to a `user_id` without going through the required function.

In other programming languages with better type systems, this can be taken a step further. You can actually prohibit explicit construction like `UserID(...)` in all but one place, causing everyone to have to go through that one place in order to obtain a piece of data of that type. In Python, you can bypass the intended flow of data by explicitly doing `YourNewType(...)` anywhere. While `NewType` is beneficial over simply type aliases, it leaves this feature to be desired.

Comment: I wish I had more examples of that.  It is still not particularly clear to me what the benefits of a subtype are.

Comment: @AntonDaneyko See my edit, does it make it clearer? It's an example where `NewType` helps us model the flow of data correctly.