# How to reuse python typing annotations

Tags: python, python-typing

I like to create my own annotations or typing extensions in my project. Basically what I like to do is reuse type annotations across my project.

So, instead of typing `List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]]` hundred times, I want to save this to a python variable and reuse it that way. Sort of custom annotations.

How can we do that?

I tried `NewType = List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]]` but it doesnt work. In the sense that, the autocomplete features doesn't come up suggesting the different functions/attributes for the object.

Comment: *autocomplete features doesn't come up suggesting* - what IDE are you using?

Comment: VSCode. just to be clear, I am not asking how to setup my vscode, just wanna know the right way to reuse annotations/typing

Comment: A note, if you're on Python 3.9+, I believe, you need not `List` and `Dict`, and can use simply `list` and `dict`, which also avoids the need to import those from `typing`

Comment: I am currently using 3.8 and I have taken note. thanks for the info!

Comment: With the way you have shown you *can* reuse type annotations. You are creating a *type alias*. What is shown in the accepted answer is another way to reuse type annotations where you create a *subtype*. The difference is explained for example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63318719/difference-between-type-alias-and-newtype).

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can read about custom new types [here](https://docs.python.org/3/library/typing.html#newtype).

```
from typing import NewType, List, Dict
import pandas as pd

CustomType = NewType('CustomType', List[Dict[str, pd.DataFrame]])
```