# Which is best for defining a complex type: CustomType(TypedDict) or CustomType = NewType(...)?

Tags: python, types, type-hinting

```
from typing import TypedDict

class CustomType(TypedDict):
    id: str
    path: str
    targets: list[str]
```

or

```
from typing import NewType

CustomType = NewType("CustomType", dict[str, str, list[str]])
```

Looks like in either case I can use `CustomType` in a type hint

```
def method(arg: CustomType) -> None:
    print(arg)
```

I feel that the TypedDict method is better because it's more explicit and packs more info into it.

But not sure which is better if my goal is to simply have type hints for complex data types.

Comment: It's unlikely that you need `NewType` anyway, but probably `typing.TypeAlias` instead (the former is really a new type, so `x: CustomType = {"a": "b"}` won't succeed, explicit conversion is necessary). Comparing `TypedDict` vs alias to plain `dict` is... weird a little: they serve different purposes. `TypedDict` says: "there are keys `id`, `path` and `targets`, and they contain types as annotated", while `dict[str, ...]` says "there can be arbitrary string keys and values of one of listed types". The latter will be compatile with e.g. `{"id": ["a", "b"]}` which is probably not what you need.

Comment: See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63318719/difference-between-type-alias-and-newtype

Comment: If it is something like API response and your codebase is going to be maintained for a long time, I'd advice to spend some time and define schemas as `TypedDict`'s explicitly. This will greatly help future readers, reduce typos probability and allow easier schema updates in future - `mypy` will point out all incompatibilities.

Answer (score 3):

`dict[str, str, list[str]]` is not a valid static type in the first place, as mypy will [tell you](https://mypy-play.net/?mypy=latest&python=3.11&gist=285d1e8fe3764f38938c0583fe657883) if you run it against your second code snippet. Output:

```
main.py:3: error: "dict" expects 2 type arguments, but 3 given  [type-arg]
Found 1 error in 1 file (checked 1 source file)
```

`dict` takes a key type and a value type, not 3 separate value types for unspecified named keys. If you want to write an annotation for a dict with particular key names and particular value types for those keys, `typing.TypedDict` is the way to do that.

Use `TypedDict`.